# Is it possible to ignore project() programmatically for mongodb find()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using `project()` to get specific fields from my mongodb query (nodeJS mongoDB driver). But in my case I need the projection only in specific cases.

So if `useProjection` is `false`, the complete datasets should be returned. I handled it this way:

```
if (useProjection) {
  return Content.find(query)
    .project({
      title: 1,
      type: 1,
      category: 1
    })
    .toArray()
}
return Content.find(query).toArray()
```

Is it possible to tell `project()` to return everything as it wouldn't be used, so it would become simpler as:

```
return Content.find(query)
  .project(useProjection && {
    title: 1,
    type: 1,
    category: 1
  })
  .toArray()
```

With this, I assume `project(undefined)` would return the complete dataset. I do not find anythin in the [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html#project), if `{}` or `undefined` would be the correct parameter - if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any option to do in `project()`, but you can try query builder approach,

```
let q = Content.find(query);
if (useProjection) q.project({ title: 1, type: 1, category: 1 });
return q.toArray();
```